# How to get summary information on tensorflow RNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, tensorboard

I implemented a simple RNN using tensorflow, shown below:

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(state_size)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, batch_size, dypte=tf.float32)
```

This works fine. But I'd like to log the weight variables to summary writer. Is there any way to do this?

By the way, do we use `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell` or `tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell`? Or are they identical?

Answer (score 4):

> But I'd like to log the weight variables to summary writer. Is there any way to do this?

You can get a variable via [`tf.get_variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) function. `tf.summary.histogram` accepts the tensor instance, so it'd be easier to use `Graph.get_tensor_by_name()`:

```py
n_steps = 2
n_inputs = 3
n_neurons = 5

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs])
basic_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.variable_scope('rnn', reuse=True):
  print(tf.get_variable('basic_rnn_cell/kernel'))

kernel = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('rnn/basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0')
tf.summary.histogram('kernel', kernel)
```

> By the way, do we use tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell or tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell? Or are they identical?

Yes, they are synonyms, but I prefer to use `tf.nn.rnn_cell` package, because everything in `tf.contrib` is sort of experimental and can be changed in 1.x versions.

Answer (score 2):

Maxim's answer is great.
I found another approach useful for me where you don't have to provide names of weight variables. This approach uses an optimizer object and compute_gradients method.

Say, you calculate the "loss" after having (outputs, states) from dynamic_rnn call. Now get an optimizer of your choice. Say Adam,

```
optzr = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
grads_and_vars = optzr.compute_gradients(loss)
```

"grads_and_vars" is A list of (gradient, variable) pairs. Now by iterating "grads_and_vars" you can have all the weights/biases and corresponding gradients if any. Like,

```
for grad, vars in grads_and_vars:
    print (vars, vars.name)
    tf.summary.histogram(vars.name, vars)
```

Ref:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#compute_gradients

Comment: ah, this is very similar to pytorch. I'll give this a try. Thank you